# Changing link background and color

Tags: html, css

Currently i'm running into a problem while i'm trying to get a link button styled.

I currently have the code for unclicked button:

```
a.linktest:link{
    color:#00F;
    border: solid 0.125em #5f9eA0;
    border-radius:0.3125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#FFFF33;
}
```

and

```
a.linktest:hover{
    color: #FF0000;
    border-radius:0.3125em;
    border: solid #FFFF33 0.125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

where it references class "linktest". The problem I run into is while I hover over the button it changes the color of the text,border, and background; the color of an unclicked button for text and border is not chaning into what i'm specifying.

Did I do anything wrong here?

edit: here's the relevant link i'm testing. http://jsfiddle.net/1zrq381o/2/

Comment: jsfiddle.net and post link (click save)

Comment: By "unclicked" you mean a button that was never clicked, or a button that is not hovered?

Comment: A button that is not hovered.

Comment: Your fiddle fails because you have an extra `}` at the top of your CSS http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1zrq381o/4/

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I just copy and pasted my code. It wasn't working before but I've fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `:link`

```
a.linktest{ /* Remove :link*/
  color:#00F;
  border: solid 0.125em #5f9eA0;
  border-radius:0.3125em;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color:#FFFF33;
}
a.linktest:hover{
   color: #FF0000;
   border-radius:0.3125em;
   border: solid #FFFF33 0.125em;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Check it working: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miike21/j32v8jya/)

Comment: It worked, though I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't work if i put :link. Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: the problem was what @j08691 mentioned, not the link pseudo attribute, you can use it without problems, you just had an additional curly bracket